# Manually Rooting - What Else Is Needed?

Tags: rooting, root-access

I have copied the `su` binary and `superuser.apk` to my device via an adb root shell. The `su` binary is in both `/system/bin` and `/system/xbin`, and I am able to successfully use it in my adb shell (for example, I get the help menu when executing `adb shell "su -h"`). The `superuser.apk` as well as a good copy of `supersu.apk` (obtained from reading other similar posts here on stackexchange) are installed in `/system/app`.

`su` has been chown'ed and chmodded with the proper permissions. I've double checked that the `superuser.apk` and `supersu.apk` have been chowned by root.

Launching `SuperSu.apk` I get a message that says "Root undetected"
`Superuser.apk` shows 2 entries in the logs as having granted root

I have tried removing each of the .apks and trying just one on the system. I've also tried different precompiled `su` binaries I've found through XDA forums and stackexchange.com

No rooted apps work properly: I never get a prompt from `Superuser.apk` to grant root permissions, and root checking apps find the `su` binary and `superuser.apk` but fail to execute as root.

**Can someone tell me what I'm missing?**

I did find some random github article for rooting a different device that mentions a `roothandler` https://github.com/Unkn0wn-0nes/RootMyValet/wiki/Manual-installation-Instructions

Please note one odd constraint: I am trying to manually root, I don't care if it's just a temporary root. Flashing via TWRP is not an option, I cannot alter/remove/backup user data from this particular device, so I don't want to risk wiping it.

Comment: You missed to include Busybox, seems that's the reason. Please also include your Smartphone details for better answers.

Comment: [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217157/218526)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to copy the busybox binary to `/system/bin` and `/system/xbin`. This may be the only step you're missing. Also, you only need one of superuser or supersu.

*edit* I was wrong, although for anyone else following along, the busybox binary from busybox.net includes su, which I thought was pretty cool. Anyway, it seems that rooting a modern android phone takes a bit more work. I took a look at the supersu zip, and from what I can tell, it creates a whole new ext4 system image and mounts it at /su. It also installs a few system daemons and initialization routines.