# How to manually root a phone?

Tags: root-access, supersu

I want to learn how to root a android phone manually, I mean without any apps like KingRoot, dr.fone etc.
I did not found any guides or information about it.

(Background Information: I want to root a BlackBerry KeyOne, even if you say it does not work i want to learn and try it anyway)

Can you please help me?

Comment: [How does Magisk work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526)

Comment: ^^that, and our [rooting tag wiki](/tags/rooting/info) are good starting points. Device-specific guides are collected in [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) (if you want device-specific help, it would be good to [edit] the title of your question and replace "a phone" by the one you're talking about, the "Blackberry KeyOne", so it can be found easier). [How does rooting work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22884/16575) will also be of interest if you want to know of "generics".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was looking at the web search results of “how to manually root Android devices” and I noticed that most of those are either just advertising stuff or makes use of dedicated (particularly closed source) rooting solutions. Those which worked some time ago are now obsolete since they depended on some [security vulnerability](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205707/218526) in Android which was fixed over time.

In fact it's not impossible to root phone manually but it's not worth the hassle. However as a reference, let me describe an option. But before diving into the technical details, we need to understand ***what root is*** and ***how Android prevents root access***. Details can be found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526) but a few points in short:

- Mostly vendors ship their devices with locked bootloader, and a chain of trust is established during boot process, which won't let any modification be done to kernel (`boot.img`), recovery or the main OS. So the first step towards rooting is [unlocked bootloader](https://source.android.com/security/overview/implement#unlockable-bootloaders). Beware of the [risks](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/info-android-device-security-privacy-t3637290)!
- A part of the chain of trust is `dm-verity` ([`VB`](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/)/[`AVB`](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/avb)); a kernel based phenomenon which makes sure that partitions containing core OS (`/system`, `/vendor`, `/odm`) are always mounted read-only and any malicious attempt to modify them must fail. Modifying `boot.img` or `recovery.img` is usually accompanied by [disabling `dm-verity`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215907/218526) to avoid surprises like bootloops at later stages. TWRP's standard warning:

  > **This device uses dm-verity!**
  >   This means that swiping to allow system modifications will prevent you from being able to boot if you are using the stock kernel.
- Similarly some vendors particularly Samsung go beyond normal and build extra security features in their devices like Knox, RKP, Defex, proca, TIMA, FIPS, bla bla bla. So you might also need to circumvent those e.g. by building kernel with `SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y`, patching kernel binary etc.
- Android apps don't have capabilities to elevate their privileges by executing binaries which have `setuid` or file capabilities set (which is the standard way to get root access). So the only option is to run a background persistent process (daemon) with root privileges outside the apps (e.g. during boot process) and request it to do privileged tasks on behalf of unprivileged apps when needed.
- Root (i.e. UID 0) is the old Discretionary Access Control (DAC), but Android also makes use of Mandatory Access Control (MAC) i.e. SELinux. A root process running with restricted SELinux context is quite helpless, so we have to break this barrier too. It requires modifying SELinux policy.

I'll address the last two points here, but first two considerations:

- Android rooting solutions deploy a special `su` binary which - when executed by an app - makes a connection to privileged daemon and gets the app a root shell. So this `su` binary and daemon are specially developed for this purpose. A less sophisticated approach would be to run already available daemons like [`adbd`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213429/218526), [`sshd`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209918/) or one of the old [inetutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/inetutils.html) flavors (`telnetd`, `rlogind`, `rshd`, `rexecd`) with root privileges. When running in background, these servers can provide a root shell or execute commands with root privileges when connected by a client. For the sake of simplicity I'm using only a minimal network utility named `netcat` (`nc`) which is a [busybox](https://github.com/yashdsaraf/bb-bot/releases) applet. But please note that **apps can't get root access with this approach**, it can only be used from commandline.
- We are going to patch monolithic `/sepolicy` file and `/init.rc` file which are part of `ramdisk` in `boot.img`. But starting with [Treble](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/#hidl) Android uses [split policy](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/init/selinux.cpp#24) which is loaded/compiled from `/system/etc/selinux/` and `/vendor/etc/selinux/`. Starting with [SAR](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root), there's no ramdisk at all in `boot.img` and `/init.rc` is part of `system.img`. So in both cases you need to necessarily modify `system` partition. I'm not giving details on that here.

**STEPS:**

- Extract `boot.img` e.g. using [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775) or [`magiskboot`](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/tools.html#magiskboot) on Android or PC.
- Create a new SELinux context, say `pseudo_su`. Set it permissive so that to allow any possible interactions with other processes / files etc. Use Magisk's [`supolicy`](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/tools.html#magiskpolicy) tool or `sepolicy-inject` <sup>([1](https://github.com/xmikos/setools-android), [2](https://github.com/phhusson/sepolicy-inject))</sup> on Android or PC:

  ```
  ~# supolicy --load sepolicy --save sepolicy 'create pseudo_su' 'permissive pseudo_su' 'dontaudit pseudo_su * * *' 'allow pseudo_su * * *' 'allow * pseudo_su * *'
  ```

  Or to build `split-policy` using [Android's compiler](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r50/init/selinux.cpp#331):

  ```
  ~# /system/bin/secilc -m -M true -G -N -c $(cat /sys/fs/selinux/policyvers) -o sepolicy /system/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy.cil /system/etc/selinux/mapping/$(cat /vendor/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy_vers.txt).cil $([ -f /vendor/etc/selinux/vendor_sepolicy.cil ] && echo /vendor/etc/selinux/vendor_sepolicy.cil /vendor/etc/selinux/plat_pub_versioned.cil || echo /vendor/etc/selinux/nonplat_sepolicy.cil)
  ```

  <sup>* Get the value of `POLICYDB_VERSION_MAX` from your [kernel source](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-3.18/security/selinux/include/security.h#40).</sup>

  To use vendor's `precompiled_sepolicy` or build from `split-policy` and patch:

  ```
  ~# supolicy --load-split --save sepolicy 'create pseudo_su' 'permissive pseudo_su' 'dontaudit pseudo_su * * *' 'allow pseudo_su * * *' 'allow * pseudo_su * *'
  ```
- Define an [`init` service](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526) which starts a simple TCP server on boot, only listening to on-device connections:

  ```
  # /init.rc
  ...
  service pseudo_su /sbin/busybox nc -lk -s 127.0.0.1 -p 23 -e /sbin/busybox sh
      seclabel u:r:pseudo_su:s0
      disabled

  on property:sys.boot_completed=1
      start pseudo_su
  ```

  <sup>* Make sure you get the right `busybox` binary, there are multiple [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Ports_and_reimplementations) of `netcat`.</sup>
  <sup>* Use port `23` or any other unused port.</sup>
- Copy updated `sepolicy` and `init.rc` to root of extracted ramdisk, `busybox` binary to `[ramdisk/]sbin/` and set permissions.
- Repack `boot.img` and flash or test with `fastboot boot boot.img`.

**HOW TO RUN ROOT COMMANDS?**

Once booted, we can pass commands from a `netcat` client on terminal emulator app (like Termux) or `adb shell`:

```
~$ echo id | /sbin/busybox nc localhost 23
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=u:r:pseudo_su:s0
```

<sup>* Default SELinux policy doesn't allow apps traverse `/sbin`. So either inject allow rules or put `busybox` in `/system/*bin/`. Or use some other `nc` e.g. from Termux's `netcat` package.</sup>

For ease of use, create functions (put them in `.bashrc` so that you don't have to define every time):

```
# ~/.bashrc
...
function psu() { echo "$@ 2>&1" | /sbin/busybox nc localhost 23; }
function psush() { /sbin/busybox nc localhost 23; }
```

```
~$ ls -ld /data/adb
ls: cannot access '/data/adb': Permission denied
~$ psu ls -ld /data/adb
drwx------ 7 root root 3488 2019-07-19 00:44 /data/adb
```

To get root shell:

```
~$ psush
whoami
root
^C
```

But it's just a [dumb shell](https://blog.ropnop.com/upgrading-simple-shells-to-fully-interactive-ttys/), not connected to terminal. To have a more feature-rich experience, other tools like [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/README) can be used which support line editing, pseudo-terminals etc.
Also environment variables aren't evaluated unless explicitly passed, because commands are executed remotely:

```
~$ /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ps -p $$,1 -o pid=,comm=
23599 bash
~$ psu /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ps -p $$,1 -o pid=,comm=
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ps": library "libprocps.so" not found
~$ psu LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ps -p $$,1 -o pid=,comm=
    1 init
23599 bash
```

So that's how we can get a minimal root functionality without using any specialized rooting tools.

---

**RELATED:**

- [How does SuperSU provide root privilege?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217532/218526)

Comment: what you mean by "android's compiler"? Isn't `secilc` something available for ubuntu in general? Do I have to compile something from AOSP to run `/system/bin/secilc -m -M true -G -N -c $(cat /sys/fs/selinux/policyvers) -o sepolicy /system/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy.cil /system/etc/selinux/mapping/$(cat /vendor/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy_vers.txt).cil $([ -f /vendor/etc/selinux/vendor_sepolicy.cil ] && echo /vendor/etc/selinux/vendor_sepolicy.cil /vendor/etc/selinux/plat_pub_versioned.cil || echo /vendor/etc/selinux/nonplat_sepolicy.cil)`?

Comment: Maybe you meant running this inside the Android, right? Can't I run on Ubuntu since it has `secilc` on apt-get?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs you can run `secilc` on Linux distros too. But you need to copy the required files to PC and then compiled binary back to the device. Android devices already have the `secilc` binary. So it's better to run the command on the device.

Comment: Would it work on a non-rooted device? Because I want to run this exactly for rooting but I guess it wouldn't run

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs theoretically it should. And also the whole process was practically performed on a non-rooted device before I wrote this answer.