# is an SD card mounted with setuid mode?

Tags: sd-card

Related question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217313/305984) which gives all the gory details (that I won't repeat in this question), motivations and context.

Android is a Linux kernel based system. I know quite well about [mount(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) and [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) and the filesystems on Linux.

Can the SD card in a tablet be mounted (e.g. as an Ext4 file system) without the `MS_NOSUID` flag? If yes, how?

I am willing and capable of writing, cross-compiling, and building a statically linked ELF executable (for my ARM-based tablet), which is `root`-[setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) and mixes the features of `sudo` and `sash` on my Debian system. I am capable of formatting some SD card (on my Debian) as an Ext4 filesystem. And if I know how to install and run it on my tablet, I will write that program as a GPLv3+ software (in C).

A related question is what exact cross GCC compiler should I use on Debian/x86-64 to target such an ARM tablet.

Answer (score 3):

- [External storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#InternalVsExternalStorage) (`/sdcard`) and physically external storage both are mounted by `vold` with `nosuid` irrespective of the filesystem, can't be mounted other way without root.
- Both storages are accessible to apps as [emulated filesystem](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526) (with fixed file permissions) or through [SAF](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider); both don't let files be executed.
- You can move ELF executable to somewhere on `/data` e.g. to `/data/local/tmp/` using `adb shell` or to `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/` using Termux app. `/data` is formatted as `ext4` or `f2fs`, lets file permissions be set, so you can execute files there. But that too is mounted with `nosuid` by default.
- Android apps are run with all Linux capabilities dropped (empty bounding set and `NO_NEW_PRIVS` set), so they can't make use of `setuid` or file capabilities to elevate their privileges.

You may want to have a look at [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526) or [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217157/218526) to see how root works on Android devices, not possible with locked bootloader.