# Cxxdroid can execute c++ binary in any internal storage directory, but Termux cannot

Tags: file-permissions, termux

I was testing some c++ executable in my old smartphone (Android 8, no root). Here's the description of the problem:

I have both Termux and Cxxdroid installed in that phone. And in termux, I have clang installed.

Let's enter Termux.

```
cd /storage/emulated/0/c++    # current dir is now c++ which sits in the internal storage
ls    # this prints 'hello.cpp', a simple hello world program. let's compile it.
clang++ hello.cxx -o hello
ls    # this prints two files now, hello and hello.cxx. let's execute hello.
./hello    # prints: bash: ./hello: Permission denied. let's grant permission.
chmod +x hello
./hello    # prints: bash: ./hello: Permission denied
```

As you can see, there's no way I can execute hello in the c++ directory. I know that if I move hello in $HOME and run it, it would work right away. But that's not the case.

Now, let's enter Cxxdroid.
Enter 'Terminal' from left menu. Let's execute our hello binary.

```
cd /storage/emulated/0/c++
ls    # contains two files. hello.cxx and hello (which is the binary generated from Termux clang). let's run it.
./hello    # prints 'Hello World'
```

See? The same binary does not run in Termux but runs right away in Cxxdroid. Why? What technique is Cxxdroid using under the hood? Permission of the hello binary for both Termux and Cxxdroid is:

```
ls -l hello    # prints: -rw-rw---- 1 root everybody 115588 Apr 25 00:32 hello
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "*What technique is Cxxdroid using under the hood?*" You can ask the developer directly. But files in emulated storage aren't executable. That's the expected behavior. See my answers to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217356/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208927/218526

Comment: @Irfan Latif Thanks for the suggestions. But, do you know any way to grant execute permission in emulated filesystem without root?

Comment: No you can't, even with root. It's a limitation of the filesystem. That's how Android's storage is designed. Read my answers for details.

Comment: You can find out yourself. Implement a hello world program that in the end waits for user input, then check via `ps` what processes are running and where they are located. I would assume that Cxxdroid simply copies the files to be execute to the internal storage where execution is allowed. Or is has a loader wrapper that allows to execute the wrapper which then loads the file to be executed that replaces all the process RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to root access. without root you can try this

```
cp /storage/emulated/0/c++/hello $HOME
chmod +x $HOME/hello
$HOME/hello
```